# Delete unwanted records from BIG File using Python or Map reduce

Tags: python, file, mapreduce, compare, bigdata

i have 37 M record in Source file but target ave only 3000 records i want to remove the additional records and only need those 3000 records. Any fastest solution in Python ?

Comment: You have to show us what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if it's easier to delete what you don't want or just keep what you do want, because you didn't provide any sample data.  Anyway, I just tested the script below and it worked fine for me.

```
with open("C:\\path_here\\test.txt","r+") as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in new_f:
        if "return_3y" in line:
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

On a 5MB file, it took just a second to do the work.  For your 37MB file, I'm guessing it will take a few seconds to do everything.  Not too bad...